# restrict user to upload image name which does not match with format using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, regex, image, validation

I have fixed image names like n.png,n@2x.png,n@4x.png . Where n is a number(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

I have to restrict user to upload image name which does not match with this format.

Suppose if some one try to upload a.png,a@2x.png,a1@4x.png,1.1@2x.png etc. should not allow and give error message.

For this  I have a form

```
<form id="app_form" name="app_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label for="appname">Image </label>
 <input type="file" onchange="validate(this);"  class="browse" id="image" name="image[]" value="" style="width:200px;float:left;" multiple="">
 <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn-blue">Update</button>
</form>
```

Javascript function

```
 function validate() {
        var uploadImg = document.getElementById('image');
        //uploadImg.files: FileList
        for (var i = 0; i < uploadImg.files.length; i++) {
           var f = uploadImg.files[i];
           var Extension = f.name.substring(f.name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
            if ( Extension == "png" || Extension == "webp" || Extension == "jpeg" || Extension == "jpg" || Extension == "PNG" || Extension == "WEBP" || Extension == "JPEG" || Extension == "JPG") {
                //    alert(f.name);
                    var one = new RegExp("@2x");
                    var two = new RegExp("@4x");
                    var x = f.name.substring(0, f.name.lastIndexOf('.'));
                    var y = x.substring(0,x.lastIndexOf('@'));
                    if (isNaN(x) == true){
                        if (one.test(f.name) ) {
                             alert(' Valid image 1');
                        } else if (two.test(f.name) & !isNaN(y)) { 
                           alert(' Valid image 2');
                        }
                      return false;
                    }else{
                        alert(f.name + ' In valid Image');
                        return false;
                    }

                    if (uploadImg.files && uploadImg.files[0] ) {
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.onload = function(e) {
                            $('#image').attr('src', e.target.result);
                        }
                        reader.readAsDataURL(fuData.files[0]);
                    }
                }else {
                    alert("Photo only allows file types of PNG, JPG, JPEG and WEBP. ");
                     var fuData = document.getElementById('image');
                     fuData.value='';
                }
           }
    }
```

But it is taking 1@2x.png as invalid image.

Note:

Allowed extension  is png ,jpg,jpeg,webp only, n.png,n@2x.png,n@4x.png here n can be any number between 1-9,user can upload multiple images at same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex will match exactly n.ext, n@2x.ext and n@4x.ext (where n is a number between 1 and 9 and ext belongs to the extensions you allowed in your note) and nothing else :
`^[1-9](?:@[24]x)?.(?:png|jpeg|webp)$`
Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/PEQPRY/2)
You can then use javascript to filter them out.
**Edit :** Just saw your note, i've added the other file extensions.

---

Here is a working javascript code :

```js
var regex = /^[1-9](?:@[24]x)?.(?:png|jpeg|webp)$/;
var fileName1 = "2@2x.png";
var fileName2 = "a3.jpeg";

if (fileName1.match(regex)) {
  console.log(fileName1+" is Valid");
} else {
  console.log(fileName1+" is Invalid");
}

if (fileName2.match(regex)) {
  console.log(fileName2+" is Valid");
} else {
  console.log(fileName2+" is Invalid");
}
```

Comment: This is for javascript or PHP

Comment: @Urvashi Hmmm... Yeah ? What's the problem ? The above regex works for both.

Comment: I gave code,In that put this it is checking for one image name after that it is not alerting anything

Comment: @Urvashi Well, I'm sorry, but I'm not going to write your code for you. I already gave you a regex that matched what you want to forbid. Then all you have to do is to test each string and if the regex matches, you return an error.

Comment: @gawil....I tried.But it is not working now.I will check deeply and let you know.Thasks

Comment: @Urvashi Ok I'm in a good day, see the javascript code above, and try to use it to adapt your own code.

Comment: Work perfectly...Thanks @Gawil you save my day

Comment: :-)) Thank you so much